# how to pass ParentController Property to custom action filter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a `Custom Action Filter` with 3 properties as below:

```
public class TrackUser : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{        
    public string BaseUrl { get; set; }
    public string Service { get; set; }
    public HealthUtil.PageCode Pagecode { get; set; }               


    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Some logic to execute

    }
}
```

I'm trying to use this Customer Action Filter with my action as below:

```
[TrackUser(BaseUrl =baseUrl, Service =service1, Pagecode =HealthUtil.PageCode.HealthHome)]
public ActionResult AddLead(leadViewModel leaddata)
{

}
```

The property `baseUrl` is defined in ParentController class as below:

```
public static  string baseUrl
{
    get { return "http://localhost:52985/api/"; }
    //set { baseUrl = value; }
}
```

Issue is I can't pass `baseUrl` to action filter. I m getting the following error message:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Please guide and help me solving this issue.

**EDIT**
`baseUrl` in ParentController has to be a property since later code will read it from App.Config.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a method in your `ParentController` like so:

```
public class ParentController : Controller
{
    public string GetUrl()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppUrl"];
    }
}
```

Then in your filter class you can call the parent controller's method to get the url like so:

```
public class TrackUser : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public string BaseUrl { get; set; }
    public string Service { get; set; }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Some logic to execute
        var controller = filterContext.Controller as ParentController;

        if (controller != null)
        {
            var url = controller.GetUrl();

            // Use it here
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps, follow up question welcome!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try changing the definition of the baseUrl property as below in the ParentConroller class.</strike>

```
public const string baseUrl = "http://localhost:52985/api/";
```

Add below code to `OnActionExecuting` method of `TrackUser` class

```
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //get hold of the controller
        var controller = filterContext.Controller as ParentController;
        //assign the BaseUrl property from tye ParentController and use it as required
        BaseUrl = controller.BaseUrl;
        // Some logic to execute
    }
```

In the `ParentController' class Change the`baseUrl` as below,

```
//get the URL from App.Config and assign to baseUrl
public string baseUrl = "http://localhost:52985/api/";
```

Update the `AddLead` Action attribute by removing the `BaseUrl` property, as it is handled in the `TrackUser` Action filter class

```
[TrackUser(Service = service1, Pagecode = HealthUtil.PageCode.HealthHome)]
    public ActionResult AddLead(leadViewModel leaddata)
    {
        //do something with the action
    }`
```

Comment: it has to a property since I will read this value form App.Config

Any suggestion please.

Comment: @user576510 It can't be dynamic, the error message even tells you that.